# Reading From TXT File to Separate Text Boxes

Tags: c#, arrays

I have been out of the coding game for quite some time now and have forgot most of what I knew. I am looking to be able to read individual lines from a txt file and append them to separate textboxes but keep getting stumped and i'm running out of time for my deadline.

I want the code to do something like this:

Read (Line 1) from (User.txt)
Append (Line 1) to (txtFirstName)

Read (Line 2) from (User.txt)
Append (Line 2) to (txtLastName)

If possible i'd like to have the txt file read in as an array so that the individual lines can be used to fill separate textboxes.

Okay, so what I had written was this:

private void btnUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if(lstbUsers.Text == "Jordan Atkinson")
        {
           TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"*FILEADDRESS*Jordan.txt");
           txtUserFirstName.Text = reader.ReadLine();



           string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"*FILEADDRESS*Jordan.txt");
             foreach (string line in lines)
             {
                 lstvUsers.Items.Add(line);
             }

        }


    }
```

However, using the reader.ReadLine() only reads the top line and I want to be able to specify what line I want to read from.

Comment: If you've already written some code, please put it in the question so we can see what you've done and you can let us know what's not working with it.

Comment: Hi welcome, SO is not a code writing service, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free code-writing service. We're here to help you if you have a _specific_ problem with _your_ code, not to write the code for you. Please show what you have tried and what _exactly_ did not work.

Comment: Try googling "c# txt file read in as an array" - this technique is often much quicker than posting a question & sitting back waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read just a specific line from your file, you can do that this way:

```cs
int lineNumber = 10;   // the line which you want to read
string line = File.ReadLines(pathToFile).Skip(lineNumber - 1).First();
```

This code will return the 10th line of your file. If you want to append this `string` to another, you can simply use the [`+=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator) operator or [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response and I appreciate your reply. Just curious, is (pathToFile) just where I put the file path or is there a specific way of setting this.

Comment: Yes, `pathToFile` is just a `string` where you put the file path. For example:
`string pathToFile = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\text.txt";`